# In Tkinter: How to limit number of clicks on canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, event-handling

my Question:
    After creating a FIXED number of items (circles)
    on Canvas, why can't I proceed, as shown below?

```
#***********************************************************


from Tkinter import *
#========================================================
class Joint():
    def __init__(self,cv):
        self.cv=cv
        self.k=0
        if self.k<=2:
            self.doIt()
#-----------------------------------------
def doIt(self):
        self.cv.bind('<1>', self.onClick)
#-----------------------------------------
def onClick(self,event):
    x=event.x
    y=event.y
    R=5
    #update counter:
    self.k+=1
    print "in k= ",self.k

    coords=[x-R,y-R,x+R,y+R]
    cv.create_oval(coords,fill="red")
#================ MAIN ===============================
root=Tk()

cv=Canvas(root,bg="yellow")
cv.pack()

joint=Joint(cv)
```

my Question:
    After creating a FIXED number of items (circles)
    on Canvas, why can't I proceed?
    (e.g. see below)

```
print "here"
print "k= ",joint.k

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: your indentation is not correct. Also, you say you can't proceed. Why not? Are you getting an error? Is the program crashing?

Comment: you have to add extra 4 spaces before every line of code to correctly format code on SO. It is easier to do it in editor and paste code in question again.

Comment: Bryan, Once I have created the N-number of circles, I want to proceed to the line print "here" (just as an example).

Comment: Bryan, maybe I should have asked: how to get out of the event-handler and proceed in the Main?

Comment: You don't even need to modify it in your editor; select the code and then click the button that looks like `{}`

Comment: I've provided an answer below. Does this do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

After a massive bit of re-formatting, I think I've got what you are looking for. The code will now only allow you to create 5 circles. You can obviously change this number.

```
from Tkinter import *

class Joint():
    def __init__(self,cv):
        self.cv=cv
        self.k=0
        if self.k<=2:
            self.doIt()
        self.circleCounter = 0

    #-----------------------------------------
    def doIt(self):
        self.cv.bind('<1>', self.onClick)
    #-----------------------------------------
    def onClick(self,event):
        if self.k < 5:
            x=event.x
            y=event.y
            R=5 #
            self.k+=1
            print "in k= ",self.k

            coords=[x-R,y-R,x+R,y+R]
            cv.create_oval(coords,fill="red")
        else:
            print "Too many circles created"


root=Tk()

cv=Canvas(root,bg="yellow")
cv.pack()

joint=Joint(cv)
""" my Question: After creating a FIXED number of items (circles) on Canvas, why can't I proceed? (e.g. see below) """

print "here"
print "k= ",joint.k

root.mainloop()
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "why can't I proceed?".